# How can this constructor that has pointer as the parameter receive string?

Tags: c++

This is a constructor that I found from the internet, but it didn't have enough descriptions so I couldn't understand how it's even possible for this constructor to have string as a parameter.

For instance, if I say `MyString str1("hello world` this "hello world" goes into the constructor, but I have no idea how this string can get into this const pointer parameter. Can anyone explain how this is possible?

```
MyString::MyString(const char* str) {
  string_length = strlen(str);
  string_content = new char[string_length];

  for (int i = 0; i != string_length; i++) string_content[i] = str[i];
}
```

Comment: Don't post links to images to code; put the actual text in the question.

Comment: `"hello world"` is a `const char[12]` array, which *decays* into a `const char*` pointer to the 1st char `'h'` in many contexts, such as in a function parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is happening is the constructor doesn't actually receive a string, it receives a pointer that points to something of type char (and what is a string if not a sequence of chars, and I mean the concept of string and not the string object in C++ itself).

When you do "MyString str1("hello world")" what is actually passed to the constructor is a pointer that points to the first char of the string, in this case the "h" char.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a const char* you are getting what is called a C string, which is a pointer to an array of characters that ends with a special value '0/' which you dont have to type. All strings that you write as literals in the code are of this form.

Dont confuse C strings with the C++ class strings (that works with C strings underneath) since are different.

Comment: More info about it https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm